# How to deflate a byte array using java.util.zip?

Tags: java, zip

I have this code to compress float values, but the size of the output is bigger than the original.

Mi goal is save the compressed data (byte array) in a file, then inflate the data to get the original float value.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public void floatToArrayByte() throws IOException {
    float f = 3574.34568f;

    byte arayByte[] = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putFloat(f).array();

    System.out.println("Original values");

    for (int i = 0; i < arayByte.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(arayByte[i]);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    System.out.println("");  

    arayByte = this.compress(arayByte);

    System.out.println("Compress values");

    for (int i = 0; i < arayByte.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(arayByte[i]);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    System.out.println("");
}

public byte[] compress(byte[] data) throws IOException {
    Deflater deflater = new Deflater();
    deflater.setInput(data);
    deflater.setLevel(Deflater.DEFLATED);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
    deflater.finish();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while (!deflater.finished()) {
        int count = deflater.deflate(buffer);
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }
    outputStream.close();
    byte[] output = outputStream.toByteArray();
    System.out.println("Original size: " + data.length + " Bytes");
    System.out.println("Compressed size: " + output.length + " Bytes");
    return output;
}
```

This is what I get

Original values

69 95 101 -120

Original size: 4 Bytes

Compressed size: 12 Bytes

Compress values

120 -38 115 -115 79 -19 0 0 3 -121 1 -110

Comment: Is this your intention to compress four items? Good chances are that you are not going to save much space. Even with 400 floats the result may be a wash, especially if the floats are random.

Comment: I am gonna compress a climate data set with thousand of records, and all of the values are float values.

Comment: Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

For very short inputs (like just 4 bytes in your case) you will always get a 'compressed' value longer than the input, because the compressed stream contains some headers.

Try to compress more data (like 100 thousand floats) to see the difference.